# How to get id from html Objects with Jsoup - Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to find the id of html objects with Jsoup.

```
<object id="gamediv" </object>
```

I tried:

```
String startingURL = "http://www.example.com";
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(startingURL)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .timeout(1000*5) //it's in milliseconds, so this means 5 seconds.              
            .get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Elements get = doc.select("object");

for (Element elem : get){
    if (get.attr("id") != null){
        System.out.println(get.attr("id"));
    }
}
```

but nothing happens. Any help please?

Comment: It works fine for me (I corrected your example to `<object id="gamediv" </object>`). Are you sure that `object` is part of `doc`? Did you try printing it `System.out.println(doc);`?

Comment: You also need to change `get.attr("id")` to `elem.attr("id")`.

Comment: Also use `doc.select("object[id]");` to select only `object` with `id` attribute (this will allow you to skip `attr("id") != null` check)

Comment: When I view the the source code, there is an html object. When I print the doc, there isn't. :/

Comment: Try turning off JavaScript in your browser and reload that page. Do you still see that `<object..>` in source code?

Comment: No, I can't. So I need to get the information inside the <script> tag. Is that possible with Jsoup?

Comment: You can try, but I would suggest using Selenium web driver. Jsoup is simply parser, not browser emulator like Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can reduce your code to simple.

```
for (Element elem : doc.select("object[id]")) {
    System.out.println(elem.attr("id"));
}
```

Secondly if `doc` doesn't contain `object` you are looking for, it means that it wasn't sent to it by server. There may be few reasons where most often ones are

- incorrect user agent header,
- this HTML code is generated by browser via JavaScript.

First case doesn't seem to apply here, so in case of dynamic content you should probably use other library since Jsoup is only parser, not browser emulator. If you are looking for more powerful tool take a look a web drivers like Selenium.